# How do I get artifacts from one Maven module included in the resources of another in my build?

Tags: maven-2

I have Maven modules that produce a Flex application as an SWF file. I want to include that file in a web application that is made with another Maven module from the same build. I'm wondering how and at which lifecycle phase I get Maven to grab the artifact from the other module and put it insode the appropriate folder of the webapp module. Would I use a separate assembly module?

The web app is running on a Jetty server in an OSGi environment (using Pax), the server side of the web app uses Struts. The final artifact as I see it would be a WAR file including my Action etc classes, JSP templates, static contents such as CSS or JS, and the SWF movies. I might be better off with these split over some other setup, but right now, I wouldn't know which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering how and at which lifecycle phase I get Maven to grab the artifact from the other module and put it insode the appropriate folder of the webapp module.

What about using <strike>[`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html)</strike> [`dependency:copy`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) during [`prepare-package`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)?

Comment: That sounds right, but do you know if it really *unpacks* the dependency? I would be dealing with a .swc (essentially a .jar), and I would want it packed into the .war in one chunk, not unwrapped. I'll test, but if you know already, I could skip that.

Comment: @Hanno Then `dependency:copy` might be better.